# How can you get a 4.2 release of g++/gcc for windows?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

How can you get a recent release, i.e. 4.2+, of g++/gcc for windows? Mingw's standard g++ is 3.4.5 which is 3 years old, released Nov 2005. Mingw have a 4.2 version but this is only in the Alpha stage. I cannot find a stable recent release of g++ for windows, surely I must be missing something.

Answer (score 8):

[Twilight Dragon Media](http://www.tdragon.net/) track and regularly release GCC releases usable for MinGW environments.

The current release is based on GCC 4.3.2.

The packages can be downloaded [here](http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/). I've started using the 4.3.2-TDM1 release in production after testing it extensively for over two months. The only iffy thing I hit is cross-DLL exceptions in C++, but C++ exceptions have been broken in MinGW for ages and most of our code doesn't use them anyway, or ar least doesn't use them across library boundaries.

There's a more recent release available (4.3.2-TDM2, been out for a couple of days). The release notes say it "differs from the first only in two bugs that have been fixed -- one related to temporary files and one related to header paths. A new TDM/MinGW installer has been released concurrently." Haven't tested it yet, though.

Edit: 4.3.3-TDM1 appears to be stable so far - haven't come across any errors in pre-production use. After having tested it exensively, I can recommend 4.3.2-TDM2 for production use.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com).  The [full package list](http://cygwin.com/packages/) includes [gcc4-g++](http://cygwin.com/packages/gcc4-g++/), and the latest version there is 4.3.2-1, which should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a MinGW distro that uses gcc 4.3.3 [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) - I've played with it but not used it in anger. It comes complete with boost and several other useful libraries